# Executing a Mutation with GraphQL in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, graphql, http-post, graphql-mutation

```
function Run_Mutation(){
  
  var token = "Bearer [Censored]"
  var Business_ID = "[Censored]"
  var url = "https://gql.waveapps.com/graphql/public";
  
  var query = 
 "mutation Mutation($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {\
  customerCreate(input: $input) {\
    didSucceed\
  }\
}";
  
  var variables = {
  "input": {
    "businessId": Business_ID,
    "name": "Santa",
    "firstName": "Saint",
    "lastName": "Nicholas",
    "email": "santa@example.com",
    "address": {
      "city": "North Pole",
      "postalCode": "H0H 0H0",
      "provinceCode": "CA-NU",
      "countryCode": "CA"
    },
    "currency": "CAD"
  }
};
    
    var headers = {
      'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
      'contentType' : 'application/json',
      'authorization' : token
  }
    
    var data = {
        "operationName": "Mutation",
        "query" : query,
        "variables" : variables
      }
    
    var options = {
      'method' : 'POST',
      'headers' : headers,
      'payload' : data
    }
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

The script above is an example mutation request in GraphQL. Specifically this is interacting with the Wave Accounting API to create a customer for a specific business, the Token and Business ID are censored for obvious reasons, and the customer is just a placeholder.

This script functions perfectly on the Wave API Playground, and even on a third party platform like Apollo. However, when plugged into Google App Script, I get the error:

> POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?

How would I be able to integrate body-parser middleware into my script? I assume that it only doesn't work on G.A.S. because the other two services I mentioned have body-parser middleware that can interact with the Wave API server. And if not that, how would I be able to make a mutation request in G.A.S.?

Query requests work perfectly fine, mutations are the only issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your script, `'contentType' : 'application/json'` and `'muteHttpExceptions' : true` are used in the request header. And, at `'payload' : data`, the object of `data` is not converted to the string. When I saw the official document of GraphQL API, it seems that the data is sent as `application/json`. [Ref](https://developer.waveapps.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018856171-Clients) I thought that the reason of your error of `POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?` might be due to this.

From this situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
  var headers = {
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'authorization' : token
}
  
  var data = {
      "operationName": "Mutation",
      "query" : query,
      "variables" : variables
    }
  
  var options = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'headers' : headers,
    'payload' : data
  }
```

#### To:

```
var headers = {'authorization': token}
var data = {
  "operationName": "Mutation",
  "query": query,
  "variables": variables
}
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': headers,
  'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'contentType': 'application/json',
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to set `query` as follows,

  ```
    mutation Mutation($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
      customerCreate(input: $input) {
        didSucceed
      }
    }
  ```
- Please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
        var query = 
       "mutation Mutation($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {\
        customerCreate(input: $input) {\
          didSucceed\
        }\
      }";
    ```
  - To

    ```
        var query = `mutation Mutation($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
        customerCreate(input: $input) {
          didSucceed
        }
      }`;
    ```
  - or

    ```
      var query = "mutation Mutation($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {\n  customerCreate(input: $input) {\n    didSucceed\n  }\n}";
    ```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your request body (`data`) and your token are valid. Please be careful this. When an error occurs by above modification, can you confirm your request body and your token, again.

#### References:

- [Develop with Wave](https://developer.waveapps.com/hc/en-us)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)